# Android Studio Gradle Error BuildActionExecuter.withCancellationToken

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the Android Studio Latest Build 2.0 from this link:
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary

And pasted it in my Android Studio Folder. After that when I was trying to run my project I encountered this error

> Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionExecuter.withCancellationToken(Lorg/gradle/tooling/CancellationToken;)Lorg/gradle/toolig/BuildActionExecuter;

untill now I can't debug or run any project on my Android Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose another path of gradle in:

```
File --> settings --> Build,Execution --> Build Tools --> Gradle
```

If you use of ver 2 select path of installed android studio and select gradle Folder.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1.Close Android Studio

2.go to android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib

3.Delete all gradle-*-2.5 files

4. Start Android Studio again and rebuild/refresh.

It worked for me