# Android Studio Error "withCancellationToken"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

After updating Android Studio 2.2 by pasting all the files to my folder, I fail to sync my project gradle due to
`Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionExecuter.withCancellationToken(Lorg/gradle/tooling/CancellationToken;)Lorg/gradle/tooling/ConfigurableLauncher;`

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34863215/2494799

Comment: Yes, I have. I have used not only Android Studio\gradle, but also      Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.10